# Exact Same CSS Code works for one page not the other

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS stylesheet linked to a HTML page (results.html) but the CSS works only when the HTML is rendered from one route and not the other.
Both routes direct to the same HTML but CSS only works on one of them.

results.html:

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/tab.css?version=3423">

</head>
```

css works here:

```
@app.route('/kinase', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def kinase():
    search = KinaseSearchForm(request.form)
    if ...
        return k_search_results(search)
    return render_template('kinase.html', form=search)

@app.route('/k_search_results')
def k_search_results(search):
    results = []
    search_string = search.data['search']
    ...
    else:
        # display results
        return render_template('results.html', results=results)
```

but not here:

```
@app.route('/profile/<kinase>')
def profile(kinase):
    ...
    return render_template('results.html', results=results)
```

I put the .css and .html in the same root folder but no luck there either.
I also tried all hard reset/bypassing cache options.

the message I get is (not sure why its adding profile here - have no directory called profile):

> "GET /profile/static/css/tab.css?version=3423 HTTP/1.1" 404 -

whereas with the first html it seems to know where the tab.css file is:

> "GET /static/css/tab.css?version=3423 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: I can see what's happening but I can't determine exactly why. Your route is `/profile/<kinase>`, that's where profile comes from. Since your CSS link is a relative path, for some reason it thinks you are in the profile directory. What is the URI of each page?

Comment: http://localhost:5000/profile/akt1 - This is the one that doesnt work, and the one that does work is: http://localhost:5000/kinase. I also put tab.css into the templates folder (where results.html is located) and used `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tab.css?version=3423">` but still no luck.

Comment: Use an absolute path for your css file. i.e. `/static/css/tab.css?version=3423`. That way no matter what page it is path is the same.

Comment: Is this not the same as what I had before?

Comment: Notice the `/` at the beginning. But when using an absolute path it starts at document root.

Comment: ah yes perfect! that works! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are pointing to the same CSS file from different directories, you need to use an absolute path. **`/`**`static/css/tab.css?version=3423`.